# How can I change the name of the data in the column of the data that comes in the form of to list in asp?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, telerik

When the page is first opened, the data I want is taken in the form of a list on the controller side in the table I show. While I show the data in the column, I want to show the values that I entered myself. For example, the page has 6 column values. The values of one column come as boolean. Naturally, it writes the values as "True" or "False" to the table. I want it to read "Open" if the value is "True" and "Close" if it is "False". How can I do it?

my .aspx code:

```
<telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="PublishOnB2B" HeaderText="Is the product Web On/Off?"
                            FilterControlWidth="100px" AutoPostBackOnFilter="true" CurrentFilterFunction="Contains" AllowFiltering="false"
                            FilterDelay="1500" ShowFilterIcon="false">
                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
```

my .aspx.cs code:

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            products = new LogicRules.B2B.BL_Product().GetAllProductsForSAPUpdate().OrderBy(x => x.ItemName).ToList();
            Session["products"] = products;
            RadGrid1.DataSource = products;
            RadGrid1.DataBind();

        }
    }
```

Here one column holds bool value. When printing values in the column it naturally writes as "True" or "False". I want it to write "Open" if "True" and "Close" if "False". I could not do it. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you want to change the data inside, you will have to loop through all records returned in the `DataTable`

```
foreach(DataRow row in dataTable.Rows) //products.Rows 
{
    if((bool) row["columnName"])
    {
        row["columnName"] = "open";
        continue;
    }
    row["columnName"] = "close";
}
```

p.s. this is not a good practice for large data

Comment: Thank you very much, sir. It hadn't occurred to me to loop through the lines. I am truly grateful.